# VaComm component doesnt fire OnRxChar event

Tags: serial-port, c++builder, serial-communication, c++builder-6

VaComm component encapsulates communication with external devices through COM port. My program is communicating with measuring device using following code:

```c
void Form::OnButton_Click()
{
   VaComm1->PortNum = param.serialComm.port;
   VaComm1->Open();
   VaComm1->WriteText("bla bla\r\n");
   Sleep(3000);
   VaComm1->WriteText("another bla bla");
}
```

I have set OnRxChar event handler (through form designer) which looks like this:

```c
void __fastcall TForm_Main::VaComm1RxChar(TObject *Sender, int Count)
{
    AnsiString str = VaComm1->ReadText();
    if (!str.IsEmpty()) 
    {
        // process received data
    }
}
```

Problem is that this event is not fired even when data were received (can be checked through calling TVaComm::ReadText method in infinite loop). Also sending of two commands to connected device was successfull (can be seen on device display). What else is needed beside opening COM port to receive OnRxChar events when there are some data in input buffer? I also don't understand what is the purpose of sibling component TVaBuffer? Currently i am not using it and can receive data through method ReadText (as i have written above).

Answer (score 2):

Most CommPort components I have seen depend on the calling thread having an active message loop in order to fire asynchronous events.  In this case, your main thread is blocked from processing new messages until OnButon_Click() exits.  Try something more like this instead:

```c
void Form::OnButton_Click()
{
    VaComm1->PortNum = param.serialComm.port;
    VaComm1->Open();
    VaComm1->WriteText("bla bla\r\n");
}

void __fastcall TForm_Main::VaComm1RxChar(TObject *Sender, int Count)
{
    AnsiString str = VaComm1->ReadText();
    if (!str.IsEmpty())
    {
        // process received data
        if (str is a reply you are expecting)
            VaComm1->WriteText("another bla bla");
    }
}
```